# Find and Replace Style on Matching Words in Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, styling

I would like to quickly find all instances of Dept_qty in my document and change them to ***Dept_qty*** (really any style change including color and font).

I would like this:
[image: Original]

To become this:
[image: Adjusted]

I can use a find to identify all instances of that word, but I still have to manually select each one and change it to the desired style.

Once the change is completed, I can use the 'Select all matching text' function to update the style to something else, but this works only for words with matching styles.

I need a faster way to update all the matching text based on the letters only.

Is this possible? Can I write a custom function to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my answer. I use regex to identify the string and manipulate accordingly:

```
function MasterPass(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  var match;

  // Find {table}.{field} patterns
  var re = new RegExp('[a-z]+_?[a-z]+[.][a-z0-9]+_?[a-z0-9]+','gi');
  while (match = re.exec(bodyElement.asText().getText())){
    highlightText(match[0].substring(0,match[0].indexOf(".")),1);
  }
}
```

This searches for strings that match the dept_qty.curr_qty pattern and highlights the string prior to the first period.  The highlightText function updates all instances of that string.